# Is it true that we are probably Boltzmann brains?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, universe

I read a post on here about boltzmann brains a few days ago, and got curious on the subject. From the articles I read, it seems that they are saying that we are almost 100 percent likely to be BBs instead of humans. These ideas have worried me tremendously.

I also read this post ([Is the Boltzmann brain problem really clearly established as a problem?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174448/)) Which only amplified my anxiety because that post seemingly says that yes, we probably are BBs.

Are those article's statements that we are almost certainly BBs true? And is that other post also correct?

Comment: would it matter, I think therefore I am. don't worry

Comment: Some people think that our universe is a simulation in an alien computer. Some people think that you have doppelgangers in other universes. Some people think that a vacuum instability could destroy our universe at any moment. Physics, like modern life, is full of  things that can provoke anxiety, and it is good to learn coping mechanisms so that you enjoy the life that you have.

Comment: Hi Curdoz. Welcome to Phys.SE. This is your 3rd question about Boltzmann brains. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: @Qmechanic The 'this is a duplicate question' on my last post said I could ask a new question, so I reformatted it and I did ask a new question. The third question you speak of was around 1 and a half years ago. Also, the post you linked as being a duplicate is not my question at all.

Comment: @Curdoz  Why would it give you anxiety?  Before your Boltzmann brain existence would (or does) end, you'd know that it (or something very much like it) would begin (and, maybe, has begun) again, after a simple, old-fashioned, relatively uncontroversial Poincare recurrence time.  Myself, I kind of like the possibility, although I try not to act on it except for occasional oversleeping.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't a Boltzmann brain.

[Sean Carroll wrote a blog post about this](https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2008/01/30/everyones-a-critic/) that you should read. It's funny, and gets its point across well.

The key point is that it's a premise of the Boltzmann brain argument that we aren't Boltzmann brains, so it makes no sense to conclude from the argument that we are.

How do we know that we aren't? I think the argument for that goes something like this.

Complex systems can arise by random chance, but the probability is low. The more complex the system, the lower the probability.

The probability of a brain randomly appearing in some location is not zero, but it's ludicrously smaller than the probability of that location containing, say, hydrogen gas.

The probability of a brain *and a surrounding body and ecosystem and fake fossils suggesting that the brain actually evolved through natural selection* appearing randomly is ludicrously smaller than the probability of just a brain appearing randomly, never mind the hydrogen gas.

Nonetheless, you can construct cosmological models so ludicrously large that the chance of the brain + fake evidence appearing *somewhere* is pretty high.

The thing is, though, that if the model is large enough for even one random brain + fake evidence to exist, it should also contain a huge number, an absolutely ludicrously huge number, of random brains without the evidence, because that's so much more likely. So, if you're a random brain, then with ludicrously high probability you should not see evidence of evolution. But you do. This is a good reason to be ludicrously confident that you aren't a random brain.

Comment: The post you link to does not make the argument you say it makes. Moreover, your conclusions don't follow from your premises. For example: it is extremely unlikely that my exact combination of genes would come together in any particular meeting of a sperm with an egg. Yet they did. Is this a good reason to be ludicrously confident that I am not the result of such a random process? Of course not!

Comment: @benrg "The probability of a brain randomly appearing in some location is not zero, but it's ludicrously smaller..." How does one decide whether something has a ludicrously small probability, or is just plain impossible? Assigning any probability at all (other than exactly zero) means that you are claiming the thing exists.

Comment: (contd. from my prev. comment) The actual argument in Carroll's post is that we only have a high probability of being Boltzmann brains if we assume the universe is vastly, vastly bigger than modern cosmology thinks it is. Boltzmann proposed that the universe was essentially a gas in equilibrium, existing over sufficiently long spatial and temporal scales that the entire observable universe could be a random fluctuation. The argument Carroll refers to is an argument against that theory. If you take that context away, it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: (Though to be honest I've always thought that argument was a bit sketchy. If there are fluctuations at all scales then there will be some at the scale of the observable universe, and the existence of lots of smaller ones doesn't change that. In addition, I'm not entirely convinced that it *is* more likely for a brain to just fluctuate into existence on its own, versus a whole universe fluctuating into existence, in which brains evolve. But this is all an aside, and probably not best suited to a comment thread.)

Comment: @Nathaniel The argument I made in my answer isn't meant to be the same as argument in the blog post. Carroll does make arguments like mine elsewhere, e.g. in [this post](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/cosmicvariance/2008/01/14/boltzmanns-universe/) which is linked from the other other one.

Comment: @Nathaniel As far as probabilistic objections go, note that "my" argument could just as well have been titled "how do we know that evolution is true?" intead of "how do we know we aren't Boltzmann brains?". I don't know how to put probabilistic reasoning on a firm philosophical footing, but I claim that if there's a problem with arguments like the one I made, then evidence is useless and science is impossible.

Comment: @benrg Your answer satisfied me a lot, especially the last paragraph. Nathaniel's first comment on your answer has worried me a lot though. Does his comment mean that the point you made in your last paragraph is false?

Comment: "But you do. This is a good reason to be ludicrously confident that you aren't a random brain." That doesn't make sense. You are engaging in the prosecutor's fallacy. "The key point is that it's a premise of the Boltzmann brain argument" ONE Boltzmann brain argument. "so it makes no sense to conclude from the argument that we are." Another non sequitur. Just because someone doesn't intend for their argument to lead to a conclusion, doesn't mean it doesn't.

Comment: @benrg Now Accumulation's response is worrying me. I feel like Accumulation is basically saying that we definitely could be boltzmann brains after all. Is Accumulation's response also true?

Comment: @Curdoz I stand by my earlier comment: all science rests on the validity of arguments of this sort. If you evolved, then by definition you're not a Boltzmann brain. If we reject evolution on the basis that the evidence might also have arisen by chance, we must reject every other scientific theory too, because they're all justified by probabilistic arguments of the same form with different numbers plugged in. Maybe I should edit my answer to just say that.

Comment: @benrg I guess what makes me more worried about Nathaniel's comment is that it made sense to me that if we were BBs, then we would almost certainly not see extreme order and other humans and whatnot. I am worried from his arguments however, that it doesn't matter if the chance for seeing order is low, the chance of you arising from actual evolution is about as low as seeing order as a BB. Is there a rebuttal for that?

Comment: One is metaphysical nonsense and the other is reality. If the probability of an organism evolving the way it did is very low and there are many ways in which an organism can evolve, then we expect that over a very long time to see a diverse group of organisms. This is reality. If a brain can spontaneously manifest out of thin air, then over a long time we expect that so could a heart, a tree, a train, or a planet appear in front of our eyes due to random chance. This not what we see. Thus this claim is false.

Comment: "The probability of a brain and a surrounding body and ecosystem and fake fossils suggesting that the brain actually evolved through natural selection appearing randomly is ludicrously smaller than the probability of just a brain appearing randomly" This is absolutely false. There is MORE chance to find an evolutionary cascade of events and environment favoring the emergence of a brain than none.

Comment: @Exocytosis are you saying that it is more likely for a randomly generated brain to think that it was evolved than for it to not think that it was evolved? Or are you saying that a brain is more likely to genuinely evolve than for a brain to randomly generate?

Comment: @Curdoz: I am saying that, based on our knowledge of physics and biology, the production of a brain through species evolution and individual growth is coherent with the rest of the universe we know of, while the spontaneous energence of a brain disconnected from its natural generation process is not and thus far more unlikely. So far cars don't grow in trees either and there's a good explanation for that: there is no continuity of the processes involved.

Comment: There is no "evidence", it is just a hallucination of the BB.  Therefore the probability isn't as low as you think

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that the argument that Boltzmann brains are more probable than our own brains is faulty.  Sure the likelihood that a naked brain will appear spontaneously is greater than the probability that a brain with a body will appear spontaneously.  But that's not how nature works.

An example:  there are an infinite number of non-spherical shapes, so a naive guess might be that a vanishingly small number of planets are spherical *assuming that their shapes result from random processes*.  But all planets are spherical.  Why?  *Because they are not formed by random processes*.

The same is true of human brains.  We, and our brains were formed by evolutionary processes as non-random as the physical processes that form planets.  Yes, randomness plays a part, but the end result is largely determined by factors that smooth out the randomness and keep the process moving toward an end state determined by a tendency to change toward the minimum energy configuration in the case of planetary shapes, and by Darwinian competition in the case of human brains.

Bottom line:  those who accept arguments asserting that Boltzmann brains exist with more likelihood than biological brains simply don't understand evolution.

Answer (score 2):

The way these things work, is that some intellectual comes up with a bizarre new theory of reality and is delighted with their own cleverness; and then some sensitive member of the public takes the words of this authority seriously, because they are an authority, and their own mental health suffers.

This happens with an idea as old and simple as determinism (am I not actually the author of my own actions, even though it feels like I am?); it happens with the many worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics (am I committing terrible acts in other possible worlds at every moment?); it happens with the idea that we are living in a computer simulation.

There is no cure-all for this, except perhaps actually achieving a knowledge of the nature of reality which the human race has not yet attained; and it is always possible that something counterintuitive will in fact be true, and yet maddeningly intolerable to the human mind. But in general, one should not believe ideas that are in radical contradiction with the bedrock facts of experience.